# Auto Filling Columns with dates with Month value in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code is supposed to autofill all the days that the selected month has, in a specific range. It should fill the dates in the range L3:AQ3 but its not filling. Its only filling the first date. Which is the `Sheets("Plantilla").Range("L3").Value...`

```
Private Sub Fecha()
Dim Mes As Date, EndDate As Date
Mes = Sheets("Llenado").Range("D2").Value
Sheets("Plantilla").Range("L3").Value = DateSerial(Month:=Mes, Day:=1, Year:=2019)
Fech = Sheets("Plantilla").Range("L3").Value
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Fech), Month(Fech) + 1, 1) - 1
Sheets("Plantilla").Range("L3:AQ3").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False
End Sub
```

Error 1004 on `Sheets("Plantilla").Range("L3:AQ3").DataSeries...`

Comment: What is the value of `EndDate` and the value in `L3`?

Comment: EndDate 31/05/2019 and L3 is 05

Comment: Are you missing part of the comment? `05` is not a date.

Comment: EndDate 31/05/2019 and L3 is 01/05/2019 my bad